# Why does switch infer an object to `never` (after exhausting all possibilities) only when assessing an union type, but not a regular interface?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, union-types

Why isn't the inference consistent between the following examples? [**Playground link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBAKgRhgXhgbxuaAuGCA0MAJgIYgm4Dkp5ClMAvjAD7qaRS4BMhNFM1MiS70mwYADMArgDsAxiACWAexmYoAZxBcAFMoBGAKygLciAJTpgMGzA0B3RSDkALPUZMgAdFiiW01rZBciQasAjYgUE2IWEwXJHRSTAATlAgUikyUdFEUBIkUgA2ILg5yTByqhrKRVBeUCkpyinuxgpefJYA9N2YLs32GjCNzSkwALTs0MoSMAbtICgwMlAAbo05DMDboBzwXMsYvrgExEJUfKLi0vJKqupaCG2eZlz+OQ5Ori8dvh8VWLhRIVWxpDJZcq2PIFYqlGBQpJVGQ1OoNJotX7eLowXrTKCzeYeBTLRAwLwUmD2FxgAD8Wx2wCAA)

```js
type T1 = { type: 1, data: 'data1' } | { type: 2, data: 'data2' } 

function test1(object: T1) {
    switch(object.type) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
            return
        default: 
            console.error(object.data) // throws error - typeof object = never
    }
}

type T2 = { type: 1, data: 'data' }

function test2(object: T2) {
    switch(object.type) {
        case 1:
            return
        default: 
            console.error(object.data) // doesn't throw - typeof object = T1 ... why?
    }
}
```

I would expect test2 to also be infered as never and throw, since there is no shape `object` can possibly take... but it doesn't.

What gives?

Comment: See [ms/TS#18056](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18056); such narrowing only happens when you have a union type, and `T2` is not treated like a "union of one member" for this purpose.  Changing it to be consistent would imply that every `if` and `switch` check on any value whatsoever would trigger the narrowing checks, making compiler performance suffer quite a bit for what turns out to be a very very small gain (people tend not to write code to narrow the number of possibilities from 1 to 0). Do you want this written up as an answer? Or am I missing something?